# История разметки комментария?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, инструменты-модератора

Если не ошибаюсь, раньше в истории комментария показывалась разметка, а теперь почему-то превью. Хочу разметку...

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Тоже хочу историю) Хотя бы своих..

Comment: Добавил перевод для `By`

Answer (score 3):

Хочется что-то изменить в движке - пиши на MSE. Тут никто не поможет. К тому же с такой узкой темой, как инструменты ромбоносного модератора. Для истории запрос может быть и полезен, но с точки зрения какого-то позитивного выхлопа - задан не в том месте.